# How do path vertices work in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, motion-graphics

I have always wondered this but never understood it. I have attempted to morph object paths in the past but I always ran into issues and just gave up. But now I have a project where I need to achieve smooth path morphs. I understand the concept of setting the first vertex to the same vertex between paths but how does the ordering of vertices work in AE? How does AE interpret vector objects designed in Illustrator and order the path points?

I have this project where I am trying to morph coins. As you can see in these screenshots I have set the first vertex to the same path point on both objects. [image: Small Coin First Vertex Reference]
[image: Big Coin First Vertex Reference]

But when I copy the path of the big coin and paste it on the last keyframe of the small coin the morph ends up in a really random position off composition.
[image: Small to Big Coin Morph Path Issue]

What could be the cause of this?